# What is differences of bitcoin mempool anchestor and descendant?

Tags: mempool

is there a specific explanation about the differences between mempool anchestor dan descendants?

there are RPC commmand for "getmempoolanchestors" and "getmempooldescendents". What is mempool anchestor and decendents it self?

each node may have a different mempool size, but what are the differences of the mempool anchestor dan descendants?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some context. I would guess you mean transactions that depend on each other, but it appears as if you assume the mempools themselves are anchestors or descendants.

Answer (score 4):

Given a transaction, there are inputs to that transaction which are spent to new outputs. The inputs themselves are outputs from a previous transaction. E.g. in tx 1, person A sends BTC to person B. Then, in tx 2, person B uses those outputs to create another transaction to person C.

1. A -> B
2. B -> C

Transaction 1 is an ancestor of transaction 2, because without transaction 1, #2 is not valid (the outputs do not exist). Likewise, transaction 2 is a descendant of transaction 1.

The RPC commands let you list ancestors/descendants of any given transaction, which are in the mempool (have not been mined and included in a block yet).

> getmempooldescendants "txid" ( verbose )
>
> If txid is in the mempool, returns all in-mempool descendants.

See [getmempooldescendants](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/blockchain/getmempooldescendants/)

> getmempoolancestors "txid" ( verbose )

If txid is in the mempool, returns all in-mempool ancestors.

See [getmempoolancestors](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/blockchain/getmempoolancestors/)